# Why the record_path in pandas.json_normalize has inconsistent behaviour?

Tags: json, pandas

This problem has been confusing me for months. I'm wondering why neither the documentation nor any question here on Stack Overflow is providing a clear explanation of the `record_path` parameter. My theory is that nobody has it, and I hope I'm wrong.

My input is this data :

```
json_input = {
    'Data': {
        '_type': 'Forecast',
        'BaseUrl': {
            '_forServiceTimeFormat': 'time',
            '$': 'http://example.com/'
        },
        'Class': [
            {
                '_displayName': 'Rainfall',
                'Service': {
                    '_name': 'ServiceName',
                    'ClassName': '_Precipitation_Rate',
                    'ImageFormat': 'jpg',
                    'times': {
                        '_defaultTime': '2023-09-19T12:00:00',
                        'time': [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                '_displayName': 'Cloud',
                'Service': {
                    '_name': 'ServiceName',
                    'ClassName': '_Total_Cloud_Cover',
                    'ImageFormat': 'gif',
                    'times': {
                        '_defaultTime': '2023-09-19T15:30:00',
                        'time': [2, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60]
                    }
                }
            },
          ]
    }
}
```

Using `df = pd.json_normalize(json_input['Data'], ['Class'])` I can get :

```
  _displayName Service._name    Service.ClassName Service.ImageFormat Service.times._defaultTime                          Service.times.time
0     Rainfall   ServiceName  _Precipitation_Rate                 jpg        2023-09-19T12:00:00  [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
1        Cloud   ServiceName   _Total_Cloud_Cover                 gif        2023-09-19T15:30:00  [2, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60]
```

But when I add `['Service', 'times']` to the path, I get an error :

```
df = pd.json_normalize(json_input['Data'], ['Class', 'Service', 'times'])
```

> TypeError: {'_name': 'ServiceName', 'ClassName': '_Precipitation_Rate', 'ImageFormat': 'jpg', 'times': {'_defaultTime': '2023-09-19T12:00:00', 'time': [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]}} has non list value {'_defaultTime': '2023-09-19T12:00:00', 'time': [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]} for path times. Must be list or null.

My expected output is this dataframe :

```
  Service.times._defaultTime
0        2023-09-19T12:00:00
1        2023-09-19T15:30:00
```

I'm looking for your help, guys.

Comment: the error says "Must be list or null.". also `json_normalize` docs states "Path in each object to list of records" https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html

`record_path` should be pointing to the json that has a list type. `['Class', 'Service', 'times']` is pointing to an object.

Answer (score 0):

Service and Times are under the main key Class so need to go further. Class is the json object Service and Times are dict objects which paths have already been normalized.

Code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=json_input.get("Data"),
    record_path="Class"
).filter(items=["Service.times._defaultTime"]).rename(columns=lambda x: x.split(".")[-1])

print(df)
```

Output:

```
          _defaultTime
0  2023-09-19T12:00:00
1  2023-09-19T15:30:00
```

Technically you can skip record_path:

Code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=json_input.get("Data").get("Class")
)

print(df)
```

Output:

```
_displayName Service._name    Service.ClassName Service.ImageFormat Service.times._defaultTime                          Service.times.time
0     Rainfall   ServiceName  _Precipitation_Rate                 jpg        2023-09-19T12:00:00  [1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50]
1        Cloud   ServiceName   _Total_Cloud_Cover                 gif        2023-09-19T15:30:00  [2, 6, 12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48, 54, 60]
```

I'm not 100% sure what you don't understand but basically if you include just data like so:

Code:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(
    data=json_input.get("Data")
)

print(df)
```

You can see json data in column Class:

```
      _type                                                                                                Class BaseUrl._forServiceTimeFormat            BaseUrl.$
0  Forecast  [{'_displayName': 'Rainfall', 'Service': {'_name': 'ServiceName', 'ClassName': '_Precipitation_R...                          time  http://example.com/
```

You would use record_path to parse the data. If it's nested and you have json data in a deeper level of Class you would just nest your record_path as well.

Comment: I would be so greateful if you can explain in detail the record_path parameter. Thank you so much Jason.